# I need to change the value of a specific column of a dataframe using condition format while imported multiple Excel file

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd

batch=pd.read_excel('batch.xlsx')
stock_report=pd.read_excel('Stock_Report.xlsx')
Result_stock=pd.merge(stock_report,batch[['Batch','Cost price']], on='Batch').fillna(0)
Result_stock2=pd.merge(Result_stock,batch[['Item number',' Batch MRP']], on='Item number').fillna(0)
Result_stock2['Total']=Result_stock2['Posted quantity']*Result_stock2['Cost price']
```

I need to change the value of `Column(Total)` for `Result_stock2` by multiplying it with two column value if it has 0.

Comment: Sorry, lost you at `by multiplying it with two column value`. Please also provide a **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn some formatting. Please format your code so we can read.

Comment: import pandas as pd

batch=pd.read_excel('batch.xlsx')
stock_report=pd.read_excel('Stock_Report.xlsx')
Result_stock=pd.merge(stock_report,batch[['Batch','Cost price']], on='Batch').fillna(0)
Result_stock2=pd.merge(Result_stock,batch[['Item number','Batch MRP']], on='Item number').fillna(0)
Result_stock2['Total']=Result_stock2['Posted quantity']*Result_stock2['Cost price']

Comment: "batch=pd.read_excel('batch.xlsx')
stock_report=pd.read_excel('Stock_Report.xlsx')
Result_stock=pd.merge(stock_report,batch[['Batch','Cost price']], on='Batch').fillna(0)
Result_stock2=pd.merge(Result_stock,batch[['Item number',' Batch MRP']], on='Item number').fillna(0)
Result_stock2['Total']=Result_stock2['Posted quantity']*Result_stock2['Cost price']"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you mean and your script is working fine so far, you should just simply add:

```
Result_stock2.loc[Result_stock2['Total']==0,'Total']=(****OPERATION YOU NEED****)
```

example in 'OPERATION'

```
 Result_stock2.loc[Result_stock2['Total']==0,'Posted quantity']*(Result_stock2.loc[Result_stock2['Total']==0,'Cost price']-5)
```

It's not a beautiful code but will do what you need.

Comment: I too get the fine output for example:

Comment: I too get the fine output for example: in the Column Value am getting the ouput based on the Result_stock2 condition, but in some case am getting the value as zero,during that case may i know what will be the condition to call the value to replace the zero with some other value from other column